# How to pass authorization bearer-token to non-authorizer lambda function through api gateway?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a node lambda function that I want to decode and read the payload of a jwt.  I created a get method with lambda proxy integration enabled, and i'm only passing the authorization bearer-token to the endpoint.  When i do this, `event` is completely empty.  How can i pass the jwt to the lambda function?

Comment: How are you passing the token? In the Authorization header? As a query parameter?

Comment: Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

If you return the event and it's empty then it sounds like some type of configuration is not set up correctly rather than the authorization header not being passed.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html) the proxy integration requires the lambda output in the following format:

```
{
  "isBase64Encoded" : "boolean",
  "statusCode": "number",
  "headers": { ... },
  "body": "JSON string"
}
```

Make sure your Lambda returns a similar output.